# Unable to authenticate postgres user during capistrano deploy on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I'm attempting to deploy a rails app to AWS.  The deploy fails with

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

My `database.yml` file (merged by capistrano from the shared dir under my app root) looks like this

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tpms_prod
  username: postgres
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
```

and the `pg_hba.conf` is the default and looks like this

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I've tried changing the authentication settings in `pg_hba.conf` to `password` but that still reports a failing Ident authentication!

I've tried adding a new super user to the database and using that user in the `database.yml` file - but the ident auth fails for that user as well, so I know that the `database.yml` file is being used by the deploy process.

If I understand the ident mechanism correctly, then the user requesting the connection just has to 'be' a declared user and this is borne out on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

might be wrong.... but for me ident means that you must have the same username between the database (the db user must be created) and the client (here it's rails).

it means that if you want it to work, you should run your rails app as "postgres" user (which might not be the best idea)